# Change CSS in CMS block

Tags: css, cms-block

Need to change the styles of a category without using the CSS sheet.

Could you help me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: Sorry for the bad understanding of the question. What i mean is that i dont have directly access to change the CSS as i am a client but i want to create a personalized category with my knowledge... Is it posible to inserta the CSS styles of a block through the CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be honest, we didnt get your question. But if you want to apply some css or js for static blocks, you can **[use this extension](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/magento-js-css-for-static-blocks)** (I own) for that. It is completely free.

For more detail about the extension, you can **[checkout my blog post](http://rajeev-k-tomy.blogspot.in/2014/08/js-and-css-for-static-block-magento.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to believe you really need to change a style without using CSS. You might not want to include a new css file or edit some one.

So, you can use CSS in-page using the layout update section in the form category, like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="custom.css.category">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<style type='text/css'>MY CUSTOM STYLES HERE!</style>]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Or maybe you want to do it only with javascript, but deep down you are still applying CSS to overwrite existing style's theme.